# How can I end a loop once each row and column in a 3x3 tic tac toe board is filled with X's and O's?

Tags: c

So I ask the user to enter X's and O's after the tic tac toe board is completely filled with X's and O's I want the program to end and not continue asking to input values into the board after they already been filled. So I made an integer variable count and set it to 0. After each time both players get asked to enter an either X or O, I want it to increment each round and once count is equal to 10 I want the entire it to break out of the do while loop and end the function. But this seems to not work and keeps asking the user to enter X's and O's. Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.

```
void CreateBoard(int m, int n, char board[][n])
{
    int i, j, position;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        SCAN:
        printf("Enter the number of the cell you want to insert X or O or enter -1 to exit: \n");
        scanf("%d", &position);

        if(position < 0){
            break;
        }
        if(position > 9){
            goto SCAN;
        }

        printf("Type X or O: \n");

        switch(position)
        {
            case 1: scanf(" %c", &board[0][0]); break;
            case 2: scanf(" %c", &board[0][1]); break;
            case 3: scanf(" %c", &board[0][2]); break;
            case 4: scanf(" %c", &board[1][0]); break;
            case 5: scanf(" %c", &board[1][1]); break;
            case 6: scanf(" %c", &board[1][2]); break;
            case 7: scanf(" %c", &board[2][0]); break;
            case 8: scanf(" %c", &board[2][1]); break;
            case 9: scanf(" %c", &board[2][2]); break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
            if (j != 2)
                printf(" | ");
            }      
            if (i != 2)
                printf("\n------------");
            printf("\n");
        }

        count++;

        if(count == 10){
            break;
        }
    }while(position != -1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one problem.

Let’s deskcheck it:

When the `do` block starts, `count` is 0. At the end of the block, it’s 1. Is `1 == 10`? Nope. Next.

`count` is 1. At the end, it’s 2. Is `2 == 10`? Nope. Next.

`count` is 2. At the end, it’s 3. Is `3 == 10`? Nope. Next.

etc. until:

`count` is 9. At the end, it’s 10. Is `10 == 10`? Yes. Out.

Let’s count how many times you’re inside the block: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. It’s 10.

So, 10 is one too many. You know the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from adeishs contains the solution to your problem. I just wanted to, if I may, make a few observations that may be helpful.

### Use of `goto`

First is the use of the `goto` keyword. It is generally considered bad practice to use it on a loop in the way that you have. You would be better off not using it, and using another conditional structure. For example ([***see here***](https://ideone.com/xM15y8)),

```
// See it in action here https://ideone.com/xM15y8
do
{
    printf("Enter the number of the cell y....");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    const bool input_is_valid = (position == -1) || ((position > 0) && (position < 10));
    if (input_is_valid)
        break;
    printf("\nInput invalid, try again\n"); 
} while(true);
```

I have added a check for the input of a zero as this is also an invalid input to your program, as far as I can see.

### Use of `scanf()`

There is a further improvement you could make too. There is a problem with `scanf()`... the standard says this:

> > ...the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behaviour is undefined...

So if a user were to type something like 8589934592, although they'd clearly be rather silly to, the is no telling what the variable `position` may hold as the value entered cannot be represented by an `int` because it is too large. A safer way might be to use `fgets()` to read stdin into a small buffer and then use `strtol()` to parse the input.

### Board Size Is Restricted

One other limitation of the function `CreateBoard()` is that is accepts a board of any dimension, but the function only allows positions 1 - 9 to be input. The `switch` statement can't do anything more than this. You could deal with this in two ways.

The row index into your board is integer division of `zero_indexed_position/num_cols`. This translates to `(position - 1) / n`.

The column index is the remainder of the above - `(position - 1) % n`.

So we could write, intead of the `switch` ([***tested here***](https://ideone.com/L30oHE) ),

```
const int row = (position - 1) / n;
const int col = (position - 1) % n;
scanf(" %c", &board[row][col]);
```

The other way would be to index the board using `*((int *)board + (position -1))`, taking advantage of how the array is laid out in memory.